# How to disable button for a specific user

Tags: node.js, discord.js

Is there a way I can make it where a user can't use a button unless they have a specific permission like ADMINISTRATOR for example?

The below code is for my ticket system, and I was just looking for a solution for when the user created the ticket, they would not be able to close it with the `️ close` button unless they had permissions to do so.

It would be much appreciated if I could have assistance on this because it would be annoying if the user opened a ticket and closed the ticket right away in a spammy way.

```
const { MessageEmbed, MessageActionRow, MessageButton } = require("discord.js");
const botconfig = require("../../botconfig");

module.exports = {
  name: "ticket",
  aliases: ["new"],
  run: async (client, message, args) => {
    let channel = message.guild.channels.cache.find(channel => channel.name === `ticket-${message.author.id}`)
    if (message.guild.channels.cache.find(channel => channel.name === `ticket-${message.author.id}`)) {
      return message.reply({ content: `You currently have an open ticket.\n<:CL_Reply:909436090413363252> <#${channel.id}>` });
    }

    const ticketEmbed = new MessageEmbed()
        .setTitle("__Support will be will you shortly__")
        .setDescription("> While you wait, please let us know how we can help\nClick on the ️ to close this ticket")
        .setColor("GREEN")
        .setFooter(`User ID: ${message.author.id}`, message.author.displayAvatarURL())
      
      const deleteTicket = new MessageActionRow().addComponents(
        new MessageButton()
          .setCustomId("delete")
          .setLabel("️ Close")
          .setStyle("DANGER")
      );
      //support ping for later references - <@&705344500578648119>      
    
    message.guild.channels.create(`ticket-${message.author.id}`, {
        permissionOverwrites: [
          {
            id: message.author.id,
            allow: ["SEND_MESSAGES", "VIEW_CHANNEL"]
          },
          {
            id: message.guild.roles.everyone,
            deny: ["SEND_MESSAGES", "VIEW_CHANNEL"]
          }
        ],
        type: "GUILD_TEXT"
      })
      .then(async channel => {
        message.reply({ content: `<:CL_Support:912055272275599380> Your ticket has been created!\n<:CL_Reply:909436090413363252> ${channel}` });
        channel.send({ content: `@here <@${message.author.id}>`, embeds: [ticketEmbed], components: [deleteTicket] });

        const logchannel = message.guild.channels.cache.find(channel => channel.name === "ticket-logs");
        if (logchannel) {
          const ticketLogs = new MessageEmbed()
            .setTitle("__New Ticket__")
            .setDescription(`A new ticket was created\n<:CL_Reply:909436090413363252> ${channel.name}\n\nCreated <t:${Math.floor(Date.now()/1000)}:R>`)
            .setColor("GREEN")
          logchannel.send({ embeds: [ticketLogs] });
        }
      });
  }
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check flags with the [has](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Permissions?scrollTo=has) method on member permissions and after you just need to disable if he doesn't has it

```js
const { Permissions } = require('discord.js');

if(!message.member.permissions.has(Permissions.FLAGS.ADMINISTRATOR) {
  deleteTicket.components[0].setDisabled(true);
}
```

Comment: Ok so that prevents the user clicking it (which is what i wanted), but now i can't close it with the button, it disabled it for the user without perms, and disabled it for me that has admin perms.

Comment: Now it should work

Comment: Might want to remove the not operator (!) from the if statement so it works when you *do* have admin perms. Right now it says 'If they don't have admin perms, disable the button.'

Comment: Yes and it's what he wants, disable button for users except if they have administrator permission!